# Can you keep using Shapechange after dropping to 0HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

## Can you use [Shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange) again after dropping to 0 HP?

This might sound strange, but I belive that, according to RAW, you can keep using Shapechange even after getting dropped out of the previous form due to taking damage.

Specifically, the sequence of events I am thinking about goes like this:

- having X HP in your base form, use Shapechange to assume a form with Y HP
- take at least Y points of damage, but less than X+Y
- turn back into your base form†
- make your con save to keep concentrating on Shapechange - nothing in the spell says that it ends upon dropping to 0HP!
- You are now in your base form, with a nonzero amount of HP left - let's call it X' - and still have Shapchange up
- use your action to assume any new form, with the only restriction being that the new form's HP cap out at X'

I believe this last bullet point to be a valid option due to this part of the spell's description:

> *During this spell's duration*, you can use your action to assume a different form following the same restrictions and rules for the original form, with one exception: if your new form has more hit points than your *current one*, your hit points remain at their current value.

This says nothing about the last form you assumed using the spell - it's your *current* form whose HP are relevant.

While I believe this to be an obvious oversight in the spell's description - just like the fact that it doesn't actually flat out say that you turn back upon being reduced to 0 HP - I think that, according to *Rules As Written*, this is how the spell works.
**Did I miss something or am I reading this correctly?**

---

† This is never *explicitly* stated to happen, but can reasonably be inferred from this paragraph:

> When you revert to your normal form, you return to the number of hit points you had before you transformed. If you *revert as a result of dropping to 0 hit points*, any excess damage carries over to your normal form. As long as the excess damage doesn't reduce your normal form to 0 hitpoints, you aren't knocked unconscious.

Comment: I've now realized this means healing the caster basically gets you double the healing

Comment: i also believe this is just a oversight in the wording.

Comment: It does imply they missed the sentence which is in the druid's Wildshape description (which works similarly): "You automatically revert if you fall unconscious, drop to 0 hit points, or die." But not sure I can justify this assumption enough for an answer.

Comment: @PJRZ I don't think this is a question of whether they revert. It's that once they revert, the spell still hasn't ended

Comment: @Medix2 I did misread, though this reverting on 0hp is a requirement for the actual question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, you can

The spell has a duration of 1 hour.

> During this spell's duration, you can use your action to assume a different form

Nothing about reverting to your own form says it ends the spell, so it doesn’t. This is different from the *Polymorph* spell which explicitly says the spell ends when this happens.